# How to handle a Validation error (in p:dataTable) while doing ajax command

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, validation

I have a `<p:dataTable editable="true">` which contains a `<p:inputText>` that have `<f:validateLength/>`
My question is that i want to handle the validation error of this `<p:inputText>` if the users enters a value with length more than maximum in `<f:validateLength/>` 
it does not matter if `<p:inputText>` is in dataTable or not if it is in a simple form and have same validation how can i handle this validation error in my bean to do a certain business 
 I tried

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Iterator<FacesMessage> messages = context.getMessages();
```

but i get messages what to do with 
and i also tried

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
boolean validationError = context.isValidationFailed();
```

I also read the documentation [FacesContext#isValidationFailed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29)
and it does not make any new details of how using it
but it always returns false in case validation success or failure
Am i using it in wrong way or i am missing something with this function

Answer (score 0):

The [`f:validateLength`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html) checks the length of your input field depending on the `maximum` and `minimum` attributes you add to the tag, e.g.:

```
<f:validateLength maximum="5" minimum="2"/>
```

Since this is one of the JSF built-in validators you will get a standard error message that is displayed if you add a `p:message` or `h:message` tag for your component or global for the whole page (you can change the default error message if you want to).

For a custom validation you should take the `validator` attribute of `p:inputText` and bind it to a validator method in your backing bean. Then you can validate anything you like.

Comment: i know that it is a JSF built-in validator
but my question is can i handle this validation error or you mean that only own validators done can be handled

Comment: If you want to handle it in an ajax action method, it is too late, since validation happens earlier in the JSF cycle.

Comment: i want to handle validation error of JSF built-in validator is that available and why its to late and it gives red indication to the inputText if the <f:validateLength> has ajax with event onBlur

Comment: You should specify what you want to "handle". Do you simply want to change the error message that is displayed or do you want to change how the validator works. That is not clear.

Comment: i don't want to change any of these what i want is an indication in my bean that a validation error has bean occured

Comment: ajax process also walk through the hole JSF lifecycle so why it does not stop error validation or am i misunderstanding JSF lifecycle with ajax

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve is to create a custom validator and call it from the component. Since you are passing the label from the component, you can add message like **{0} XXXXXXXXXXXXX** in the validator. By this you can have different error messages for different components.
And you can configure the error messages in property files and read in the validator class.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: what i need is to know weather a validation error occured or not in my managed bean so that i can make my own business

Comment: suppose i have a table and in these table there is a validation failure although i have an add button that adds an object to the list and updates the datatable in case of validation fail in a previous row the add button excutes normally as if no failure in validation so i want to know that there was a failure in validation in the previous row so that i can stop the action of the add button

Comment: @primeFaceUser : When you are using a custom validator : (1)According to JSF LifeCycle when validtion phase fails, it render the response with the error message and without updating the backing bean object with updated values. So there is no possibillity of getting to know in the backing bean where does the validation fails.

Comment: ok thanks i understood the issue but please may you read my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985577/primefaces-editable-datatable-updates-after-validation-failure-in-previous-rows where on second ajax request with a commandButton the validation phase is skipped how does this happens

Comment: @primeFaceUser: But if you wanna know in the backing bean whether validation fails or not, the you can write a validation method in the backing bean without giving any validator in html. so your backing method will be called for your action and there you can explicitlly do the validation

Comment: by this way you mean to add my own business method in my bean and not to use the JSF <f:validateXxX>    
Is that what you meant to say

Comment: Exactly. since you want to know whether validation fails or not in backingbean, you will have to do it in backingbean. Because JSF skips all other phases and goes to render response phase if validation fails in validation phase.

Comment: @primeFaceUser : Can you make clear why you want to know validation fails or not in backing bean.?? When validation fails from validation phase it automatically throws the error message, without submitting the form.

Comment: according to my problem in the other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985577/primefaces-editable-datatable-updates-after-validation-failure-in-previous-rows where previous unvalidated rows/cells are skipped so i am trying to solve my problem by knowing the validation failure in backing bean so that i can (e.g. color the cell or row having the validation failed with a business in my bean)